# Why can't the number $\pi$ (or any transcendental number) be definable?

Tags: logic

Why can't the number $\pi$ (or any transcendental number) be definable without parameters in the model structure $(\mathbb{R}=(\textrm{real field}), <, +, .)$?

Comment: The theory of real-closed fields is complete, and has the real algebraics as a model.

Comment: Actually, the OP is asking about the theory of $\mathbb{R}$ and not the theory of real-closed fields, so your comment doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: @RobArthan I think that's the reason he mentioned it's complete.

Comment: @Anguepa: sure, but I didn't think the OP would necessarily understand the connection between completeness of the theory of real-closed fields and the theory of the reals. Anyway, it's water under the bridge.